# Chart not displaying from JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, chart.js

UPDATED: I am tying to use `ChartJS` to display a chart on a web page using data from a `Microsoft SQL Server database`. I have got the data to output onto a page in `JSON format`, however I am unable to transfer the `JSON` data onto my chart. When trying to do so, the chart does not display at all but returns a blank white page.

I have tried creating the graph by adding data directly to it, that works and displays the graph with the data. The problem I am facing is when trying the load the graph using data from JSON, it does not display the graph at all. The JSON data does not display in my browser console either. The JSON data however, does show when loading data.php file onto a webpage (for testing). See screenshot below of this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMULR.jpg

I have just removed the following line of code

```
else { // if connected successfully
echo "Connected successfully";
}
```

which was being added to JSON. After removing that line, I now get errors in my browser console when trying to load the graph. See screenshot here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPmwU.jpg

I have replaced the JQuery script to the latest version however same problem. Any suggestions please?

Below is data.php

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  $serverName = "******"; 
  $connectionInfo = array(
    "Database" => "****", // database name
    "UID" => "****", // username
    "PWD" => "****"  // password
  );

  $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);


  //if not connected successfully
  if (!$conn)  {
    die("Connection error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  } else { // if connected successfully
    echo "Connected successfully";
  }


  $sql = "SELECT Name, TestID FROM Testtable"; //create select statement
  $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql); // execute select query from database
  $data = array(); 

  while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row; //add results to data array
  }

  sqlsrv_free_stmt($result); //free result entry
  sqlsrv_close($conn); // close connection
  echo json_encode($data); //encode data to JSON
?>
```

Below is app.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost/chartjs/data.php",
     method: "GET",
     success: function(data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
        var name = [];
        var testid = [];

        for(var i in data) {
           name.push("Name " + data[i].Name);
           testid.push(data[i].TestID);
           console.log(data);
        }

        var chartdata = {
          labels: name,
          datasets : [{
             label: 'Name and TestIDs',
             backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
             borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
             hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
             hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
             data: testid
          }]
        };

        var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

        var barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
           type: 'bar',
           data: chartdata
        });
     },
     error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
     }
  });
});
```

I require the JSON data to be outputted to my chart and chart to be displayed.

Currently, the chart is not displaying.

JSON data is not being outputted to my browser console also.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is the JSON data outputted in the expected form? Is there anything written to your browser's console?

Comment: Browser console is displaying the data and JSON data is outputted in expected form, the chart just does not display. I'm a bit stuck here and don't know what else to try

Comment: I need to make a correction: I can see in my browser console (When I add 
"header('Content-Type: application/json');" to my data.php AND "data = JSON.prase(data)" in my app.js): https://imgur.com/a/iXUH4gq   This is outputting to console from line 38 from App.php. I don't understand this error, can someone explain to me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by removing the following line of code from app.php:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way to get chart is wrong, you are getting only html element, but you need to get context, you can do this like:

```
$("#mycanvas").get(0).getContext('2d');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
```

Comment: Tried this now, same issue however

Comment: Can you inspect your chart(browser inspect), there should be some js messages in console.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of that now and updated in my post

Comment: That's not an error, thats data what you get from response, it's message from `console.log(data)`, you have added it on two places

Comment: Error tab in console displays the following: "arguments: null caller: null length: 0 name: "add"" - Is that an error? What does that mean?

Comment: Seems that error is happening on JSON.parse, can you check data before that?

Comment: Adding a console log output before JSON.parse displayed the data in the log. See screenshot: https://imgur.com/8s8KXcO

Comment: hmm, I would try to convert first to array then try to parse to json